# Using *this as const in copy constructor to clone self

Tags: c++, constants, clone, copy-constructor

I am trying to implement a prototype pattern.When I pass self object with `*this` in order to clone itself with copy constructor I cannot access self member functions due to:

`error: passing ‘const ConcreteClonable1’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

The error has to do with wrong usage of `const`. However, if I remove `const` from copy constructor everything works. I want to use copy constructor as it is supposed to, with `const` argument, and the ability to access non-const class members.

Here is the code:

```cpp
/* Prototype base class. */
class Prototype
{
    protected:
        std::string type;
        int value;
    public:
        virtual Prototype* clone() = 0;
        std::string getType() { return type; }
        int getValue() { return value; }
};

//clonable class
class ConcreteClonable1 : public Prototype
{
    public:
        ConcreteClonable1(int number)
        {
            std::cout << "ConcreteClonable1 cnstr\n";
            type  = "Type1";
            value = number;
        }
        //compilation error if const is used
        ConcreteClonable1 (const ConcreteClonable1& x)
        {
            std::cout << "ConcreteClonable1 copy cnstr\n";
            type  = x.getType();
            value = x.getValue();
        }
        Prototype* clone() { return new ConcreteClonable1(*this); }
};
```

The objects are initialized in a `Factory`.

The question is why is this happening? Is there a better way to do this with some kind of [copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) function from c++ STL?

Comment: why is `getType` not `const` ?

Comment: as a rule of thumb you can make all your methods `const` and only if you need to modify `this` remove it

Comment: This question is not really about the Prototype pattern, it's just "why can't I call these member functions on a const object?" which has been asked a thousand times on StackOverflow already, and the answer is because you didn't make the member functions `const`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it should also provoke the question "why *am* I calling these member functions *at all*"?

Comment: @Caleth or even better "why did I write getters in the first place?"

Comment: @user463035818 These functions could be something else more complex. The example here is for simplicity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delegate the copy construction of `Prototype`

```
ConcreteClonable1::ConcreteClonable1(const ConcreteClonable1 & x) : Prototype(x) 
{ std::cout << "ConcreteClonable1 copy cnstr\n"; }
```

In general you should prefer member initialisation over assigning in the body of the constructor.

```
Prototype::Prototype(std::string type_, int value_) : type(type_), value(value_) {}

ConcreteClonable1::ConcreteClonable1(int number) : Prototype("Type1", number) 
{ std::cout << "ConcreteClonable1 cnstr\n"; }
```

Comment: yup, that's better

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for your answer. I have a question. Why  `: Prototype(x)` works without the need to declare `getType` and `getValue` as `const` ?

Comment: because there is a compiler generated `Prototype::Prototype(const Prototype &)` copy constructor that copies the data members directly, and doesn't involve `getType` or `getValue`

Comment: Which is why `struct pair { std::string first; int second; };` is a usable type, e.g. `pair one = { "just works", 1 }, two; two = one;`

Comment: @Caleth Using `: type(x.getType()), value(x.getValue())` returns an error `does not have any field named ‘value’`. I guess its because of abstract class `Prototype`?

Comment: You can *simply omit* ConcreteClonable1's copy constructor, and it will *just work*, albeit without any place for the `std::cout << "ConcreteClonable1 copy cnstr\n";` to go

Comment: `type` and `value` are initialised by the construction of the `Prototype` base object. The rules of constructors say you only get *one* place to initialise the data members, you *can't* do it a **second time** in a derived initialiser list

Comment: There is a call to `Prototype::Prototype()`, which occurs at the start of the member initialisation of `ConcreteClonable1`. it's nothing to do with the abstractness of `Prototype`, merely the fact that *it* has the members *directly*, `ConcreteClonable1` only has them *indirectly* through `Prototype`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `const` correctness is all over the place. The immediate problem is that `getType` and `getValue` need to be marked `const` else they cannot be used if the implicit `this` pointer is `const`, which it is in your case.

Along with this, you should also fix your `clone()` function to be `const` too (although this is not required for your immediate compilation issue):

```
Prototype* clone() const { return new ConcreteClonable1(*this); }
```

Cloning after all should not modify the current object.

Comment: I tried that and I get the same error

Comment: that's not the problem. the problem is that he uses non-const member functions in the copy ctor

Comment: @BugShotGG: You *must* change the "get" functions too.

Comment: @Sopel et al.: If you don't need to mark the `clone` function `const` then please downvote this - I'm in a meeting suffering from a mental block.

Comment: @Sopel et al. Fixed it. Yes, you're all correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba While clone doesn't need to be const; neither do a lot of functions.  I would consider correcting it as part of the fix

Comment: @UKMonkey Oh for a time machine, so that `mutable` can be the modifier, and `const` the default

Comment: @Caleth: Absolutely. And remove `std::vector<bool>` and perhaps even `bool` too. And `class` for that matter. And the fact that `'c'` is a `char` type, rather than an `int`.

Comment: @Caleth a number of people on SO (including Bathsheba I believe) have asked if I'm from the future .... so I code how I think the standard should be rather than how it is and then 'adjust' as required.  Sue me.  But agreed; I wish they'd stop putting useless things in the standard and work on features like that!

Comment: @UKMonkey: Can you let me know the outcome of the case before I consider suing you?

Comment: @Bathsheba Chuck Norris wins

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call non-const member functions of `Prototype` on the const object of `ConcreteClonable1 : public Prototype` in the `ConcreteClonable1`'s copy constructor. To make it work you have to make them const (or not use them at all, se below).

Apart from that you don't really need to know about `Prototype` to copy `ConcreteClonable1`. Just copy the members.

Comment: Thanks, making `getType` and `getValue` `const` worked. I now understand why that happened. Completely forgot the access rule of `const` and `nonconst`